# Remove horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap. For some reason there is space on the right side and I can horizontally scroll which I don't want to allow. I tried to remove some styles to find out why with firebug and saw it is coming from the `<html>` tag, when I mouse over the `<body>` tag, I can see that there is extra space on right which `body` is not covering but `html is` covering.

How can I remove that space to remove the horizontal scroll?

Comment: body worked. thanks. wanna write an answer. i ll mark u.

Comment: None of this, it's the #footer css declaration witch is buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#footer {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #010627;
  border-top: 1px solid #111111;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
  clear: both;
  color: #BBBBBB;
  margin: 2.5em -50px 0; /* <-- margin-right:-50px? */
  padding: 20px 50px;
}
```

Before 'patching' with some hoverflow:hidden, try to figure out what gets out content out of viewport.

**margin: 2.5em -50px 0; /* <-- margin-right:-50px? */**

Comment: @MilchePatern actually I think the most common comment on SO is: **What have you tried?**

Comment: @simone I think the most common comment on SO is: `Is this homework?`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to identify your problem without code, but this might be worth a try. In your body section of css, add the line:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) for more overflow options that might help you design your page in regards to scroll-bars. No guarantees, but worth a try!